# Use records update syntax for newtype

Tags: purescript

Previously I had this type:

```
type Directions =
  { top    :: Boolean
  , right  :: Boolean
  , bottom :: Boolean
  , left   :: Boolean
  }
```

And for this type I had this functions

```
empty = { top: false, right: false, bottom: false, left: false}

withLeft = empty { left = true }
```

I want to convert `Directions` to `newtype`, but I also want to use the same syntax as in `withLeft`, like this...

```
newtype Directions = Directions
  { top    :: Boolean
  , right  :: Boolean
  , bottom :: Boolean
  , left   :: Boolean
  }

empty = Directions { top: false, right: false, bottom: false, left: false}

withLeft = empty { left = true }
```

...but this doesn't work. How can I do it?

Comment: Not a 100% sure but I think you have to unwrap/wrap manually: `withLeft = let Directions empty' = empty in Directions empty' { left = true }`.

Comment: @Dogbert it seems that you are right, I found similar solution by using default record same as your `empty'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use record update syntax with `Directions` because it's, well, not a record. But you can get somewhat close.

For example, you can take advantage of *partially applied* record update with the record itself missing. The syntax is `_ { x = y }`, and it's a shorthand for `\r -> r { x = y }`.

Armed with this, you could make yourself an "update directions" function:

```hs
type DirectionsR = { top: false, right: false, bottom: false, left: false}
newtype Directions = Directions DirectionsR

ud :: (DirectionsR -> DirectionsR) -> Direction -> Direction
ud f (Directions d) = Directions (f d)
```

And then:

```hs
withLeft = empty # ud _ { left = true }
```

Incidentally, the `ud` function can also be encoded in terms of [`over`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-newtype/5.0.0/docs/Data.Newtype#v:over):

```hs
ud = over Directions
```

And of course you can use `over` directly in the body of `withLeft`:

```hs
withLeft = empty # over Directions _ { left = true }
```

But that's a bit too verbose in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me the `over` function, but in my case `ud` adds more complexity than `withLeft = Directions (empty' { left = true })`.